# give `TextFormField` dynamic controller

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a function which loads data to `TextFormField` from firebase .
can we supply `controller` to the `TextFormField` created by following function.

```
 loadDataToTextFormField(
      QuerySnapshot mySnapshot,
      int index,
      String databaseField,
      String? bulletsAndNumberingType,
      TextStyle textStyle) {
    List getDataList = List.from(mySnapshot.docs[index][databaseField]);
    return Column(
      children: [
        for (var i in getDataList)
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: TextFormField(
                //  controller: ?? how to supply controller here,
                initialValue:
                    "$bulletsAndNumberingType  $i", 
                style: (textStyle)
                ),
          ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Any Help would be highly appriciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can supply controller to the TextFormField by use following function.

```
loadDataToTextFormField(
      QuerySnapshot mySnapshot,
      int index,
      String databaseField,
      String? bulletsAndNumberingType,
      TextStyle textStyle) {
    List getDataList = List.from(mySnapshot.docs[index][databaseField]);
    List<TextEditingController> textEditingControllerList =
        List<TextEditingController>.filled(
            getDataList.length, TextEditingController());

    return Column(
      children: [
        for (var i in getDataList)
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: TextFormField(
                controller: textEditingControllerList[i],
                initialValue: "$bulletsAndNumberingType  $i",
                style: (textStyle)),
          ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Comment: Giving only the code without explanation will solve the problem but will not help him understand why it works

Comment: i think in add controller there is no need to explain.

Comment: @BhargavGhodasara .. gave me error.. expected a value of type 'int' but got one type of 'String'. Error is coming from the line `controller: textEditingControllerList[i]`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i forgot `TextFormField` can't  have both properties `controller` or 'initialValue' at oncce. It can have either `controller` or 'initialValue'.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).